# Is there a common name for this code smell?

Tags: oop, dependencies, anti-patterns

I refer to it as the "delivery boy". I've seen several variants of it but the issue is that a class has dependency for the sole purpose of passing it on to collaborators and never using the dependency itself.

(I'm using PHP because it's what I'm most familiar with but this is language agnostic)

```
class Dependency{}

class B {
    public function setDependency(Dependency $dependency) {
        //...
    }
}

class A {
    private $b;
    private $dependency;

    public function __construct(Dependency $dependency, B $b) {
        $this->dependency = $dependency;
        $this->b = $b;
    }

    public function foo() {
        $this->b->setDependency($this->dependency);
    }
}
```

Probably the most common variant I see in the wild is abusing inheritance for this purpose, having a property in the parent class which exists so that the child classes have access to the dependency even if the parent class never actually uses the dependency itself.

```
class Dependency{}



class A {
    protected $dependency;

    public function __construct(Dependency $dependency) {
        $this->dependency = $dependency;
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public function foo() {
        $this->dependency->bar();
    }
}
```

I see this in code far more than I'd like and it doesn't make me very happy! I just wondered if there was a name for this so that I can link people to reading materials on why it's a bad idea. As it stands, I don't know what to search for!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any name, but I kind of like Delivery boy... though I suppose some might consider the name borderline offensive.

Typically this problem is solved with either Dependency Injection or a Service Locator, although way too many people use Singleton for this (inappropriately).

I'm not familiar enough with PHP to know if PHP offers a real DI solution (as opposed to poor man's DI), but I think a service locator would be acceptable if there isn't (even though service locator is often a code smell in itself).

Comment: As you write `ServiceLocator` is a "better `Singleton`"; so much stress on the *`type`*, not *`object`*. OP's usage seems to have at least as much stress on the actual object, don't see how `ServiceLocator` can be used instead.

Comment: @MiserableVariable - In many cases, you don't need a specific instance, however dependency injection frameworks typically have methods to configure whether it uses an existing one, or a new one, or a pooled one, or whatever.  a service locator can certainly do the same.  Still, DI and SL are not the only solutions to this problem, but they are pretty common.

Comment: We are probably talking about two different problems if you are thinking of many cases where you don't need specific instance. To me the dependecy here is at object level rather then type level.

Comment: @MiserableVariable - cases where you don't need specific instances often revolve around unit testing, where you pass implementations into other objects as dependencies in order to abstract functionality.  Another case is where you use a factory to return specific instances.  The data itself might be specific, but the factory isn't.

Comment: Thanks, but I have to confess I don't know why you are explaining to me cases where I don't need specific instances :)

Comment: @MiserableVariable - I was pointing out that even if you need a specific instance, there are ways to get it without passing that instance directly into the object, but still using good design principles

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of the workarounds, DI being my preferred method as SL goes against "Tell, don't ask" though occasionally it is the better option. I was just interested in this specific anti-pattern and whether anyone had documented/blogged about the downsides of it and the issues it creates. Perhaps I'll do it myself. I've found myself explaining them enough anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The problem related to inheritance in the second snippet looks like to me "Broken Hierarchy". This smell occurs when the base class and its derived class do not share an IS-A relationship. It is very common to find code that uses inheritance just for convenience (for reuse) and not because it makes sense to have a hierarchy where the participating classes are are related (by IS-A relationship).

(I borrowed the smell terminology (i.e. Broken Hierarchy) from the book ["Refactoring for software design smells](http://bit.ly/DesignSmells)")